# golang отправить данные в формате json

Tags: json, golang, веб-сервер

В данный момент отправляю данные во View от сервера следующем образом.

```
func ModelListNar(id string)[]*Add_rows {
    query := "SELECT number_nar, date_open_nar, date_close_nar FROM j_nar WHERE id_patient = " + id + ""
    rows := db.Select(query)
    bks := make([]*Add_rows, 0)
    for rows.Next() {
        bk := new(Add_rows)
        rows.Scan(&bk.Name, &bk.DateOpenNar, &bk.DateCloseNar)
        bks = append(bks, bk)
    }
    return bks
}


func FormatDate(Time time.Time) string {
    return Time.Format("2006-01-02")
}


func ListNar(w http.ResponseWriter, rnd render.Render) {
    bks := models.ModelListNar(currentId.id)
    for _, bk := range bks {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "%s %s %s \n", bk.Name, FormatDate(bk.DateOpenNar), FormatDate(bk.DateCloseNar))
    }
}
```

Через "разделитель" "\n".
Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать ответ с сервера в формате JSON

и привести его к виду.

`{Name: '121', DateOpen: '16.06.1981', DateClose: '20.06.1981'}`

Спасибо.

Comment: Почему Вы не хотите отправлять строку?

Comment: Ну можно и строку, хотелось бы с JSON разобраться.

Comment: Разбиритесь с json.marshal и json.unmarshal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Евгений, вы уже который раз задаёте вопросы, которые легко решаются чтением документации. Откройте для  себя https://golang.org/pkg/.

Что же касается вашего вопроса, используйте пакет `enconding/json`. Для этого проставьте в вашей структуре (которая кстати по [стайлгайду](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments) должна называться `AddRows`) JSON-тэги:

```
type AddRows struct {
    Name         string    `json:"Name"`
    DateOpenNar  time.Time `json:"DateOpen"`
    DateCloseNar time.Time `json:"DateOpen"`
    // ...
}
```

А дальше:

```
bks := models.ModelListNar(currentId.id)
b, err := json.Marshal(bks)
if err != nil {
    http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
    return
}

err = w.Write(b)
if err != nil {
    log.Printf("error while writing: %v", err)
    return
}
```

(Кстати, по тому же стайлгайду, `currentId` должен быть `currentID`.)

Comment: Спасибо, я в web программирование не так давно и многое для меня не так очевидно как для Вас, документацию читаю, не всегда понимаю что в ней имеется введу.

Comment: @ЕвгенийГусев Пожалуйста. Ещё я заметил, что вы не отмечаете ответы на свои вопросы принятыми. Чтобы это сделать, надо нажать на галочку рядом со счётом ответа. Рекомендую пройти по своим вопросам и принять ответы, которые вам помогли, чтобы другие могли видеть, что на вопрос есть принятый ответ.

Comment: спасибо за замечание, отмечу.